# Select every specific variable only if it has the most recent timestamp

Tags: sql, qlikview

I have a table that looks like this-

```
ChangeKeyValue  ChangeFieldName ChangeOldValue  ChangeNewValue
106 OGCSTATUSID 20  10
106 OGCSTATUSID 10  20
106 DATALOADSTATUSID    10  20
106 DATAAMOUNTSTATUSID  10  20
106 OGCSTATUSID 20  10
106 DATALOADSTATUSID    20  10
106 DATAAMOUNTSTATUSID  20  10
106 OGCSTATUSID Not Yet Reviewed    Under Review
106 OGCSTATUSID 20  Not Yet Reviewed
106 DATALOADSTATUSID    Not Loaded  Loaded - Outside DSC
106 DATALOADSTATUSID    Loaded - Outside DSC    Not Loaded
106 DATAAMOUNTSTATUSID  None    Partial
106 DATAAMOUNTSTATUSID  Partial Full
106 DATAAMOUNTSTATUSID  30  None
106 OGCSTATUSID Not Yet Reviewed    Under Review
106 OGCSTATUSID 20  Not Yet Reviewed
106 DATALOADSTATUSID    Not Loaded  Loaded - Outside DSC
106 DATALOADSTATUSID    20  Not Loaded
106 DATAAMOUNTSTATUSID  None    Partial
106 DATAAMOUNTSTATUSID  20  None
106 OGCSTATUSID Not Yet Reviewed    Rejected - Do Not Load
106 OGCSTATUSID Rejected - Do Not Load  Not Yet Reviewed
106 DATALOADSTATUSID    Not Loaded  Loaded - Outside DSC
106 DATALOADSTATUSID    Loaded - Outside DSC    Not Loaded
106 DATAAMOUNTSTATUSID  None    Partial
106 DATAAMOUNTSTATUSID  Partial None
106 OGCSTATUSID Not Yet Reviewed    Under Review
106 OGCSTATUSID Under Review    Not Yet Reviewed
106 DATALOADSTATUSID    Not Loaded  Loaded - Outside DSC
106 DATALOADSTATUSID    Loaded - Outside DSC    Not Loaded
106 DATAAMOUNTSTATUSID  None    Partial
106 DATAAMOUNTSTATUSID  Partial Quarantined - DSC
```

And the timestamp looks like this-

```
2016-03-01 11:03:01.703
2016-03-01 11:37:11.117
2016-03-01 11:37:27.933
2016-03-01 11:37:30.017
2016-03-01 11:37:40.837
2016-03-01 11:37:43.250
2016-03-01 11:37:45.890
2016-03-01 12:55:47.567
2016-03-01 12:56:42.347
2016-03-01 12:56:46.917
2016-03-01 12:56:51.413
2016-03-01 12:56:54.737
2016-03-01 12:57:01.293
2016-03-01 12:57:03.500
2016-03-01 12:59:39.487
2016-03-01 12:59:43.443
2016-03-01 12:59:47.840
2016-03-01 12:59:51.410
2016-03-01 12:59:55.147
2016-03-01 12:59:57.137
2016-03-01 13:03:10.350
2016-03-01 13:03:12.450
2016-03-01 13:03:15.677
2016-03-01 13:03:17.813
2016-03-01 13:03:21.067
2016-03-01 13:03:24.127
2016-03-01 14:24:46.523
2016-03-01 14:24:52.347
2016-03-01 14:24:56.480
2016-03-01 14:24:59.363
2016-03-01 14:25:02.777
2016-03-01 14:25:05.640
```

What I want to do is select `ChangeNewValue` but only if it's the most recent timestamp. Specifically, I want to select the most recent timestamp only if `ChangeNewValue` is `Quarantined - DSC`.

Please note that the QlikView code I am using (unsuccessfully) is as follows-

```
Left keep
Table6:
Load
ChangeKeyValue as ITMSNumber,
IF(ChangeNewValue='Quarantined - DSC', date(Today()) - Floor(date(TIMESTAMP(ChangeDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD hh.mm.ss.fff'))));

SQL SELECT ChangeKeyValue,
ChangeNewValue,
ChangeDate
FROM MPL.dbo."tblCHANGE";
```

The table name is `MPL.dbo."tblCHANGE"`

I request that you please use the labels that I put in this post in your answer so as to avoid confusion.

Comment: Is this timestamp actually in the table?  Why is is separate?

Comment: What's the underlying DBMS?

Comment: The timestamp is in the table and I don't know what you mean by DBMS. I'm assuming it means Database Management Structure?

Comment: It's SQL Server being used through QlikView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what did it for me.

```
SQL
    SELECT  ITMSNumber,Date_Chg,DATEDIFF(dd,Date_Chg,GETDATE()) AS tDays
    FROM    tblSTRATEGY Strgy
        inner join
          ( SELECT  ChangeKeyValue AS ITMS_Chg,MAX(ChangeDate) AS Date_Chg
            FROM    tblCHANGE Chg
            WHERE   ChangeFieldName='DATALOADSTATUSID'
                AND ChangeNewValue='Quarantined - DSC'
            GROUP BY ChangeKeyValue
        ) Chg1 ON Chg1.ITMS_Chg=Strgy.ITMSNumber
    WHERE   Strgy.DATALOADSTATUSID=30
    ORDER BY TDAYS;
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

SQL server / Oracle:

```
with CTE as
(
select a1.*, row_number() over(partition by ChangeFieldName order by TimeStampField) as R_ORD
from MyTable a1
)
select *
from CTE
where R_ORD = 1
and ChangeNewValue = 'Quarantined - DSC'
```

MySQL:

```
select *
from 
(
select ChangeFieldName, max(TimeStampField) as maxField
from MyTable
group by ChangeFieldName
) a1
inner join MyTable a2
on a1.ChangeFieldName = a2.ChangeFieldName
and a1.maxField = a2.TimeStampField
and a2.ChangeNewValue = 'Quarantined - DSC'
```

Comment: Please check the edit to the original post. This is being done in QlikView so please keep that in mind. I did your SQL Server code and it didn't get the results I was hoping for.

Comment: I also just tried your MySQL code. ALthough for either of them there is no error, the numbers are way off.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SQL:
SQL SELECT ChangeKeyValue,
ChangeNewValue,
ChangeDate
FROM MPL.dbo."tblCHANGE";

left join (SQL)
Load max(ChangeDate) as Max_ChangeDate 
resident SQL
where ChangeNewValue='Quarantined - DSC';

Table6:
Load
ChangeKeyValue as ITMSNumber,
date(Today()) - Floor(date(TIMESTAMP(ChangeDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD hh.mm.ss.fff')))
resident SQL
where ChangeDate=Max_ChangeDate and ChangeNewValue='Quarantined - DSC';

drop field Max_ChangeDate; drop table SQL;
```

for less code you can also use `inner join` or `right join` but this should work pretty good